# Ai have problems with the installation of Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

The installation of Ubuntu 14.04 don't have the same steps for everyone? I'm doing the steps of installation from official website Ubuntu,and the first page is for choosing language,2 step look for me LIVE SESSION... PASSWORD??? And ai don't put any password.!!! How it's. possible??? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to the step where You have to choose a password, so you just have to write your new password.